# Does $\sum \frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, radicals

Prove that the following series converges
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}}.$$

Comment: Alternative solution: $n \sqrt[n]{n} = n^{1+1/n}$ and $1+1/n > 1$. Then use that  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^a}$ converges for $a>1$ (if you know that fact)

Comment: @Cortizol This "alternative solution" is misleading (and it yields the wrong conclusion).

Comment: @Did Please,tell me where I am wrong? Is that because $a$ depends on $n$?

Comment: @Cortizol "where I am wrong?" When you apply a result which holds for every fixed $a\gt1$, to some exponent $a_n$ which depends on $n$ (and approaches $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: is $n^{1/n}$ bigger than $\log n?$ If not, what about $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n \log n}?$ (think integral test).

Comment: Thanks. After a bit of thinking, $f(n)=n^{1/n} \leq 1/e$ for all $n$.

Comment: That is NOT true, but it _is_ smaller than some constant.

Comment: Typo, its less than or equal to $e^{1/e}$ for all $n$. Easy enough to prove using Cacl I. From W|A, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+n%5E%281%2Fn%29+over+1%3C%3Dn%3Cinfinity

Comment: Indeed, so all is well :)